# How do I make lines scale when using GLOrtho?

Tags: opengl, rendering, lines

I'm using GLOrtho to set up a 2D view that I can render textures onto.  It works really well, up until I try to zoom in on the image.  If I pass half the width and half the height of the viewport to GLOrtho, I end up with all my textures displayed twice as big as normal, which is exactly what I expect.

But then I try to draw a box around part of the image and it all falls apart. I call `glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)`, place the four vertices, and call glEnd, and I expect to see the same thing I would see if I drew it at normal zoom level, doubled.  Instead, I get lines that are all the right length, but they all come out one pixel wide, instead of two, and it looks really bad.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can either scale it yourself using glLineWidth or you can emulate the line as 2 triangles.

Comment: 2 triangles! Probably will have to enable anti-aliasing also. Great idea.

Comment: Good answer. GL lines always have a fixed width.

Answer (score -1):

[glScale](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScale.xml) would be a better solution for scaling instead of changing glOrtho parameters.
That way anything drawn will scale as expected.

Comment: Actually, glScale won't give twice the width.